# Getting value of same TextEditingController rendered via list

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm stuck at a problem: I have a method that has a few TextEditingController instances, and this method returns a widget, representing an object. It is rendered via a list, which means these controllers have as many instances as the length of the list. Now, on the click handler of a button, I want to get all the values of each widget from the controllers. I am currently saving them in a list of objects. The main problem is that when I update some text, the controller value changes, but it is already in the list, so it doesn't reflect in the object. Is there any way to get these values only when the button is clicked, without needing to store them in the list of objects? Below is the code to get an idea.

```
ListView.builder(
    controller: _deviceScroll,
    itemCount: 6,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
        child: editableAdress(), //Widget rendering
    );
})

Widget editableAdress() {
    TextEditingController _nameController =
        TextEditingController(text: adress.adrName1);

    TextEditingController _secondNameController =
        TextEditingController(text: adress.adrName2);
    
    //adding in the list
    widget.addressesList.add(new Address(
        adrName1: _nameController.text, adrName2: _secondNameController.text));

    return Column(
      children: [
        Text('NAME', style: headingStyle),
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
        Column(
          children: [
            editableTextField(context, _nameController, 'Person 1 / Firma'),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            editableTextField(context, _secondNameController, 'Person 2'),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to keep the **TextEditingController** in a list not just the text property from the controller.

```
widget.addressesController.add(
  new AddressController(adrName1: _nameController, adrName2: _secondNameController)
);
```

this way you can always access the actual value and on the button click convert to Address class.

**But if you don't want to do this, then:**

A better approach.
You can update the values with a listener.
Just preload the array with null values in string or empty strings in Addresses and pass the index to the method.

Preload:

```
widget.addressesList=List.generate(6/*Or the length you want*/, (index) => Address(adrName1: null, adrName2: null));
```

Method:

```
Widget editableAdress(int index) {
  TextEditingController _nameController =
    TextEditingController(text: adress.adrName1);

  TextEditingController _secondNameController =
    TextEditingController(text: adress.adrName2);

  //update value
  _nameController.addListener(() {
    widget.addressesList[index].ardName1 = _nameController.value;
  })

  //update second value
  _secondNameController.addListener(() {
    widget.addressesList[index].ardName2 = _secondNameController.value;
  })

  ....
}
```

This way the listeners always update the values.

Comment: Already tried the second approach; it didn't work. But the first one works. Thanks!